# how to connect to android with laravel

Tags: android, mysql, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I have created a test application on laravel with login and registration page using html and javascript. And is connected to the database and can login and register. I'm using Auth of laravel 5.2 for this example. Now I want to implement the same thing with android. And I dont know how to use the same Auth of laravel with android. Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use SharedPreferences to check user is login, register is just call web service. [more](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: the you for the quick response@rome. but what i want here is how the auth of laravel works with android?

Answer (score 0):

use JWT to do auth with Laravel. there are a component JWT with laravel . More information : http://cubettech.com/blog/api-authentication-using-jwt-in-laravel-5/

Comment: thank you @Abbes Yassine... what you gave is for web tokens... I want to know how to do it with android..

Comment: with android try to make params Authorization in Header  `@GET(url)
    Call<ResponseBody> getData(@Header("Authorization") String authorization )`  . Call this method in our Activity or Fragment like this exemple : `Call<ResponseBody> call = retrofitService.getData(accessToken, libelleSearch, user.getId());`

Comment: Use retrofit to do this . More info [link](https://futurestud.io/blog/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit)